# Translate Drools-generated facts

Tags: jsf, translation, drools, drools-guvnor

First off: If I am totally wrong with my request, please close this and point me into the right direction.

I use Drools (with Guvnor-created rules) in a JSF application for the verification of a created object. Basically, the workflow is:

1. user creates an object
2. rules are fired to check this object
3. rules for which the check fails insert a new fact into the working memory with some message, explaining why the verification failed
4. the facts are extracted from the working memory and displayed in the JSF application

My question: What is the best way to translate these messages? Are there any "best practices" for such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Translate to different languages? You can use a different properties file and resolve the right text based on those files, right? as in every application that you want to use internationalization (I18N).
Cheers

Comment: Yes, I want to translate into different languages. If I used properties files, the (non-technical!) users would have to create a new property for every single message they type, copy that property name into guvnor and add the actual message in the properties file - I don't think I could do that. Hence I am looking for a different solution or at least a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "user message" object with message ids and insert this as a fact. In the rule, set an appropriate message id. In the presentation layer, map the id to a message string in locale-specific string table.

Comment: Sounds like an option, although I'll have to check out if I can train the users to use messageIDs instead of "clear text" messages. My current strain of thought deals with a translation on the presentation side, using a database-based translation table and some caching for a decent performance. But the project is currently on hold, if I continue with this I'll share my experiences.